# how to prove $\operatorname{lub} A = \operatorname{glb} B$ where $\emptyset \neq A \subset \mathbb R$ be bounded above in $\mathbb R$.

Tags: real-numbers

Let $\emptyset \neq A \subset \mathbb R$ be bounded above in $\mathbb R$. Let $B$ be the set of upper bounds of $A$. Show that B is bounded below and $\operatorname{lub} A = \operatorname{glb} B$

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! It would be helpful for you to post your ideas on the problem so far, so we can give more useful responses.

Comment: Please see [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in our [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) and pages linked there.

Comment: Namaskar Mehta ji

Comment: Consider following two cases: $A= (-\infty, 0)$ and $A=(-\infty, 0]$. What is $B$ in these two cases? Try to solve these two cases explicitly. That will give you an idea how to solve the stated problem.

Comment: we can not take any cases because we have solve generaly  .

Comment: @AbhishekPal These are *test cases* (*examples*, if you prefer) to get an idea on the approach of the general problem.

Comment: plz give proof of it